# Extracting words from an Excel sheet through Python

Tags: python

How can I extract a word from Excel and make it a separate column by using Python?
For example: The blow text is in an excel sheet and I want to extract the "Blood group" and make it a new cloumn.

**Blood group- O Positive,HIV/HBsAg/HCV- Negative**

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hint: google for `openpyxl`

Comment: I have tried to create a new column and replicate the entire existing column and have been trying to edit the new column, but I am failing.

Comment: Please show the code.

Comment: hospital["Blood group"]=hospital['INV']

Comment: Blood group- O PositiveHIV/HBsAg/HCV- NegativeRest of 
Haemogram/Biochem- WNL.
 
PT - 13.1 on 11/01/2010 secs, INR - 1.05, 
PT on 12/01/2010 - 12.5 secs
INR - 1
PT on 13/01/2010 - 14.2
INR - 1.15
ECG- AF, HR- 100/min, QRS 96 degree

Comment: I want to extract the "Blood group" from the above chunk of data and make it a new column

Answer (score 1):

So assuming that your data looks like this:
[image]

We can do:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('doc.csv')
```

to get
[image]

and lastly

```py
split_by_comma = data.col1.str.split(',').tolist()
blood_group = [lst[0].split('- ')[1] for lst in split_by_comma]
hiv         = [lst[1].split('- ')[1] for lst in split_by_comma]
pd.DataFrame({'Blood Group': blood_group, 'HIV/HBsAg/HCV': hiv})
```

to get this:
[image]

Comment: The problem is: I have almost 3000 rows and the data is not comma separated. Few chunks do not have comma also

Comment: That's alright, the same general idea applies. This code works for any number of rows, and you can fiddle around depending on what your data looks like to split correctly. Only small adjustments are needed from what's above.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what exactly you want to extract. If its allways Blood group then you can just use a slice, if it is different words that you want to extract, then you need to provide more details for anyone to be able to help you properly.

Let me know more details on what is that you are looking for.

Comment: I want to extract the "Blood group" from the above chunk of data and make it a new column

Comment: Blood group- O PositiveHIV/HBsAg/HCV- NegativeRest of Haemogram/Biochem- WNL. PT - 13.1 on 11/01/2010 secs, INR - 1.05, PT on 12/01/2010 - 12.5 secs INR - 1 PT on 13/01/2010 - 14.2 INR - 1.15 ECG- AF, HR- 100/min, QRS 96 degree